# Checkmarx scan is reporting Leftover Debug Code for main method in Springboot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, checkmarx, secure-coding

*Checkmarx* scan runs as a step in *CI/CD* on my *Springboot Application*.

In the scan results, *Checkmarx* is reporting *Leftover Debug Code* issue, because I have the `main` method as the entry point in my *Springboot Application*.

How can I pass the *Checkmarx* scan?

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JNDIConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, TransactionAutoConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicatiomContext.xml"})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 public static void main(String args []) {

     SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
     springApplication.run(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `main` method, including the method and class annotations?

Comment: Keep me updated after you've done it.

Comment: @baruchiro I have added the code for main method

Answer (score 1):

The Leftover Debug Code Checkmarx query is apparently looking for the "public" and "static" keywords so try to change the modifier into private or protected:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JNDIConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, TransactionAutoConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicatiomContext.xml"})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 protected static void main(String args []) {

     SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
     springApplication.run(args);

    }
}
```